# Swift semantics calling a method on a (nullable) weak reference using the ?. operator

Tags: swift, weak-references

Back in objective-C with ARC, this wasn't safe to do:

```
MyClass* someObject = ...
__weak MyClass* weakSomeObject = someObject;
doSomething(^{
    [weakSomeObject someMethod];
});
```

Why? because simply calling a method doesn't cause ARC to retain the object, and thus the `someObject` instance might be released and dealloced **in the middle** of the execution of `someMethod`

Bringing this forward into swift, it translates as follows:

```
let someObject: MyClass = ...
doSomething { [weak someObject]
    someObject?.someMethod()
}
```

#### My question is, what are the semantics of the `?.` operator in swift regarding ARC, and is it safe to use with weak reference method calls?

I can imagine the swift compiler translating the above code into something like this:

```
let someObject: MyClass = ...
doSomething { [weak someObject]
    if let tmp = someObject { 
        tmp.someMethod()
    }
}
```

If it did that, then it would indeed be safe, as `tmp` is a strong reference and thus would cause ARC to retain the object across the duration of the call to `someMethod`

However, I could also imagine it translating into something without an ARC retain for performance reasons or whatever.

Does anyone know what it actually does, and is there a specification or document that makes this explicit?

Comment: Is the block/closure necessary in a minimal example?

Comment: Your opening implies that Objective-C with ARC isn't a thing anymore.

Comment: For me, it's not. If you're still writing new code in ObjC, more power to you, I just chose to use swift these days instead

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, it is safe.  Longer explanation and link follow:

Methods defined for a type in Swift are curried functions like this:

```
class MyClass {
  func doSomething() {
      // I can access self in here
  }
}

print(type(of: MyClass.doSomething)) //(MyClass) -> () -> ()
```

In other words, the function defined on the type is curried such that it must first be passed a reference to what will be `self`, which is strongly captured in the returned partially applied function (`()->()`)

When you call the method on an *instance* of MyClass (not the type itself), it automatically does the initial partial application of passing in that instance of `self` which is then captured strongly by the resulting closure that is actually invoked.

So the type of `MyClass.doSomething` is `(MyClass) -> () -> ()`, and the type of `MyClass().doSomething` is `() -> ()`, where the initial MyClass reference is already captured inside the `() -> ()`.

Given the below code:

```
weak var test: MyClass? = MyClass()
test?.doSomething()
```

On line 2, a couple things happen. First, if `test` is non-nil, it will be passed to the the method implementation on the *type* MyClass and captured by the MyClass type's curried function `(MyClass) -> () ->()`. This captured reference is the "self" that can be used inside that instance method.

Then, the resulting partially applied function of type `()->()` is invoked, and the strong reference / capture of `self` from above is released once the function executes.

So, the answer is then *yes*, it is safe to call instance methods on a weak reference, because the instance method actually strongly captures the instance up until and while it is executing.

This post discusses how instance methods in Swift are curried in more detail, and links to the initial dev forum source of the information.

https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/

---

### UPDATE:

Some additional interesting and in-depth articles on this mechanism:

http://rosslebeau.com/2016/sneaky-reference-cycles-swift-instance-methods

https://www.klundberg.com/blog/capturing-objects-weakly-in-instance-method-references-in-swift/

Comment: I note that in swift 3 the currying syntax was removed: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md
Does this mean the underlying behaviour changed? Does it still work the way you say it does? (The referenced blog post is from 2014 which predates the currying removal, which casts doubt on it)

Comment: @OrionEdwards This proposal removed special shorthand syntax for declaring curried functions. It didn't remove the ability to curry functions (possible in any language with first-class functions like Swift) and it didn't change the way methods are implemented as curried functions. You can easily verify this in a Playground using the sample code in my answer, e.g. `print(type(of: MyClass.doSomething))` will show you the curried function type.

Comment: @OrionEdwards I added some additional article links which cover different aspects of this mechanism

Answer (score 0):

Bullet points to get first:

- closures capture context.
- if let, guard etc only checks if optional contains actual value but doesn't capture it's context.

Now about `?`. It's optional chaining, if object on which method is called is nil, it won't call method as well as fail full chain(if you follow up return value from method with another method call or else).

About `weak` and `unowned` references to used objects inside closure:

- `weak` doesn't create strong reference to object, so it makes it optional because object may not be there when it gets called
- `unowned` as well as `weak` doesn't create strong reference, however object won't be optional, so you must guarantee that closure won't outlive object it uses, because you will get crash referencing object that isn't there.

Hope it helps.